# Entity-Component: What is the clear() method used for?

Tags: jhipster

After generating Angular code for an entity the `entity.component.ts` file contains a method named `clear()`.
It is quite similar to `transient()` but not eactly the same. It seems it can be delete without breaking anything.

1. What is it for? When should I use this method?
2. Why is `router.navigate` using a different notation?
3. Why is the query param `size: this.itemsPerPage` not included?

When generating Angular-Code for an Entity with  the entity.component.ts file

This code gets generated when the entity has `"pagination": "pagination"` (and `"jpaMetamodelFiltering": true`) specified.

```js
  transition() {
    this.router.navigate(['/entity'], {
      queryParams: {
        page: this.page,
        size: this.itemsPerPage,
        sort: this.predicate + ',' + (this.reverse ? 'asc' : 'desc')
      }
    });
    this.loadAll();
  }

  clear() {
    this.page = 0;
    this.router.navigate([
      '/entity',
      {
        page: this.page,
        sort: this.predicate + ',' + (this.reverse ? 'asc' : 'desc')
      }
    ]);
    this.loadAll();
  }
```

Comment: `transition` is used for things like pagination while `clear` as I see it is a hard reset on the current route (that's why itemsPerPage is not included, it will take the default value). I suspect `clear()` was more useful when the update component was a dialog. The question about different `navigate()` usage has to do with using queryParms vs matrixParams, but I'm not very experienced in this so I'll wait for someone else to answer.

Comment: I came to a similar conclusion, but `clear` isn't a real hard reset as I see it. It keeps the current `sort`, which seems inconsistent to me